# Querying a MongoDB based on Mongo ID in a node.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongodb-query

I'm using a node.js and mongodb, and I'm trying to query the database based on the mongo generated ID using the following:

```
    collection.findOne( {_id:doc._id} , function(err, item) {});
```

I am 100% certain that my doc._id is an exact match to the doc _id that I am looking for in the collection, and yet I get a null response from the db query.

I have tried this using other keys in the document and it returns the document just fine. It's only when I try to use the mongo ID.

Comment: Is `doc._id` a string representation of the ObjectId or an actual ObjectId?

Answer (score 17):

The MongoDb is an object not a string. To convert my string I used:

```
    var id = require('mongodb').ObjectID(doc._id);
```

This converts my string into a mongo ObjectId and matches the _id in the db!

Answer (score 10):

Following is the example which spots the issue:

```
var mongo = require('mongodb'),
    Server = mongo.Server,
    Db = mongo.Db,
    ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient

//let id = your _id, smth like '6dg27sh2sdhsdhs72hsdfs2sfs'...
var obj_id = new ObjectID('52cbd028e9f43a090ca0c1af');
var justId = '52cbd028e9f43a090ca0c1af'; // <== This will not work

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/YourDbName', function(err, db) {
    console.log('err'  +  err);
    db.collection('YourCollectionName', function(error, collection) {
        //collection.find({_id:justId}),function(err, docs) { // <== This will not work
        collection.findOne({_id:obj_id},function(err, docs) {
          console.log("Printing docs from Array. count " + JSON.stringify(docs)); 
        });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 7):

Use this:

```
ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
```

Then when you try to find an object in collection by _id use this:

```
 console.log("find by: "+ id);
 database.collection("userRegister").findOne({_id: new ObjectId(id)}, 
   function(err, res) { 

     if (err) console.log(err);

     if(res!=null){
       console.log(res)
       return false;
     }

     if(res==null){
       callback({'status':_error,'flag':'notexist','message':_userNotExist});
       return false;
     }

   });
```

Answer (score 5):

First we need to get `ObjectID` from `mongodb` library and need to create new instance in following way., so that you will get the ObjectID of string. If your are using **es6** in your code this code

```
import { ObjectID } from 'mongodb';

var emQuery = [
          {
            $match: {
              _id: new ObjectID(tlvaltResult[0].customers.createdBy)
            }
          },
          {
            $project: {
              _id:1,
              emailId:1,
              mobile:1
            }
          }
        ];

console.log(emQuery,'emQuery');

[ { '$match': { _id: 5ad83ff0b443435298741d3b } },
  { '$project': { _id: 1, emailId: 1, mobile: 1 } } ] 

var emResult = await User.getAggregation(emQuery);

console.log(emResult,'emResult');

[ { _id: 5ad83ff0b443435298741d3b,
    emailId: 'superAdmin@limitlessmobile.com' } ]
```

Answer (score 2):

First, ensure you've added all required modules in MongoDB config:

```
var mongo = require('mongodb'),
    Server = mongo.Server,
    Db = mongo.Db,
    ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
var BSON = require('mongodb').BSONPure;
var server = new Server('localhost', 27017, {
    auto_reconnect: true
});
var db = new Db('YOUR_DB_NAME', server);
```

Then, when you try to find an object in collection by _id, use:

```
//let id = your _id, smth like '6dg27sh2sdhsdhs72hsdfs2sfs'...
var obj_id = BSON.ObjectID.createFromHexString(id);
db.collection("NAME_OF_COLLECTION_WHERE_IS_YOUR_OBJECT", function(error, collection) {
    collection.findOne( {_id:obj_id} , function(err, item) {
        // console.log ( item.username );
    });
});
```

Hope, this works.