# Spring Boot Mongo findById returns null

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-mongodb

I have a collection, with documents having a field named `_id` of type `String`, not generated manually.

I have been trying to get a document using its id.

```
    val criteria = Criteria.where("_id").`is`("a2z3e44R")
    val document = mongoTemplate.findOne(Query.query(criteria), MyDocument::class.java) // returns null

    val criteria = Criteria.where("_id").`is`(ObjectId("a2z3e44R"))
    val document = mongoTemplate.findOne(Query.query(criteria), MyDocument::class.java) // returns null

    val document = mongoTemplate.findById("a2z3e44R", MyDocument::class.java) // returns null

    mongoTemplate.findAll(MyDocument::class.java).first { myDocument ->
        myDocument._id == "a2z3e44R"
    } // OK...
```

MyDocument is

```
data class MyDocument(val _id: String, val name: String)
```

Trying to find a document by another field works.

An idea of what I could be missing or a workaround?

Comment: Can you please post your JSON document the way you get it through mongo.exe or Robo3T?

Answer (score 2):

Try mark `_id` with annotation `@Id`. The `@Id` annotation is used to specify the identifier for Spring.

```
data class MyDocument(@Id val _id: String, val name: String)
```

Comment: I implemented your suggestion using `import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id
` but the result remains the same.

Comment: How do you persist new data?

Comment: It is another program taking care of adding data. I am only reading them.

Answer (score 2):

You should indicate the type of the id like this

```java
public class Article {

    @MongoId(value = FieldType.OBJECT_ID)
    private String id;

    private String title;

    private String desc;
}
```

Comment: That is a winner answer

Answer (score 0):

Ypu could define in your repository:

```
public interface MyDocumentRepository extends MongoRepository<MyDocument, String> {
  Pets findBy_id(ObjectId _id);
}
```

and use it :

```
myDocumentRepository.findBy_id("a2z3e44R");
```

for more info  [see](https://medium.com/@gtommee97/rest-api-java-spring-boot-and-mongodb-4dffbcabbaf5)

or

```
ObjectId objID = new ObjectId("a2z3e44R");
      query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("_id").lt(objID));
```

like this other answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30873713/mongotemplate-query-objectid-according-to-greater-than-gt-or-less-than-lt)

Comment: This solution is not working either. This was my initial code.