# How to return mongodb client single row result in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am use  `MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;` module in NodeJs. But, i have not get single row **JSON** Object result in node. I have no any idea in mongodb client module.

Simple Query: `select *from settings where id=1;`

Mongo Query: `db.collection("settings").findOne({_id:"5860cdf634c39399937f6619"});`

**I have get multiple JSON row like:**

```
mongo.client.connect(mongo.url, function(err, db){
        var resultArr = [];
        var data = db.collection("settings").find();
        data.forEach(function(doc, err){
            mongo.assert.equal(null, err);
            resultArr.push(doc);
        }, function(){
            db.close();
            res.json({error:false,data:resultArr,msg:""});
        });
    });
```

This is working fine. But, i have not able to get single row.

I am use this library : http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/installation-guide/

Comment: findOne will return single document, so what is your expected output?

Comment: i have get this result in json object? how to get?

Comment: A javascript object IS what is returned though

Comment: what is the result you are getting?

Comment: If you are getting BSON object try with a parser. Pls refer https://www.npmjs.com/package/bson-json-transform

Answer (score 1):

I have resolve my own error!. using this reference link: [Querying a MongoDB based on Mongo ID in a node.js app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769252/querying-a-mongodb-based-on-mongo-id-in-a-node-js-app)

My Old code:

```
exports.getById = function(req, res, next) {
    mongo.client.connect(mongo.url, function(err, db){
        var id = req.params.id; // "5860cdf634c39399937f6619"           
        var data = db.collection("settings").findOne({_id:id}).then(function(doc) {
            console.log(doc);
            db.close();
        });
    });
};
```

**See my resolved code:**

```
exports.getById = function(req, res, next) {
    mongo.client.connect(mongo.url, function(err, db){
        var id = req.params.id;
        var o_id = mongo.ObjectId(id); // this is my solutions
        var data = db.collection("settings").findOne({_id:o_id}).then(function(doc) {
            console.log(doc);
            db.close();
        });
    });
};
```