# How do you find a document by id in a MongoDB Realm Function?

Tags: mongodb, realm, realm-functions

I'm writing a function in MongoDB Realm that I want to use as a custom resolver for GraphQL. Part of the function should get a specific document by its id. According to the documentation I can get access to the Atlas DB by using `context.services.get('mongodb-atlas')`. Here's the simplified code extract:

```js
exports = async () => {
  const cluster = context.services.get('mongodb-atlas');
  const collection = cluster.db('my-db').collection('my-coll');
  return await collection.findOne({"_id": "61d33d2059c38ef0584c94f8"});
}
```

However, the `findOne()` call returns `null`. I know that the id above is valid, because I can successfully call `collection.find()` and list all the documents with their ids.

### What I've tried

- `findOne({"_id": "61d..."})` - returns `null`
- `findOne({"_id": new ObjectId("61d...")})` - error: "ObjectId" is not defined.
- Explicitly declaring ObjectId with `const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId` as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64170395/3900981) - error: "MongoDB Node.js Driver is not supported".
- Declaring ObjectId with `const ObjectId = require('bson').ObjectId` - `findOne()` returns `null` again.

Can you recommend any other avenue by which to do this lookup?

Comment: Can you add `.catch(err => console.error(`Failed to find document: ${err}`));` and see if the err reveals any further details? It's a good idea to include error trapping is they can be very handy when troubleshooting - maybe so in the this case as well.

Comment: Tried it. No error gets thrown. `null` is a valid return value if no object is found. Problem is that the passed-in string is a valid ObjectId

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would suggest is - let's identify where the script is failing.
We know for certain, the below should work.

```
exports = async () => {
let tmp_collection = context.services.get("mongodb-atlas").db("my-db").collection("my-coll");
return await tmp_collection.findOne({});
}
```

After you can confirm that the above works, give this a try:

```
    return await context.services.get("mongodb-atlas").db("my-db").collection("my-coll").findOne({"_id":new BSON.ObjectId("61d33d2059c38ef0584c94f8")});
```

Here is your code, but fixed:

```
exports = async () => {
  const cluster = context.services.get('mongodb-atlas');
  const collection = cluster.db('my-db').collection('my-coll');
  return await collection.findOne({"_id": new BSON.ObjectId("61d33d2059c38ef0584c94f8")});
}
```